# The base class includes the field 'Head1', but its type is not compatible

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web application, it's showing a below error :-

> The base class includes the field 'Head1', but its type
>   (HimalayanCraft.head) is not compatible with the type of control
>   (ASP.usercontrols_head_ascx).

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables with the same name.

`Head1` is a type of `HimalayanCraft.head` which conflicts with the `Head1` field of type `ASP.usercontrols_head_ascx`.

Rename one or the other (or change the type to match).

Answer (score 1):

If it's really not a syntax error, unckeck the build (and publish) option "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable"

It might not be enought for the runtime, so check the option "use fixed naming and single page assemblies" and it solved my case :)

here is a useful link about this error: http://forums.asp.net/t/960707.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479044.aspx